# Code to skip a column whilst copying and pasting

Tags: excel, vba

Complete VBA newbie, already had a question answered by someone else earlier, which was lifesaving! They assisted me with the below code, so that I could copy, paste and transpose on to the next available line of an Excel workbook.

I now have blank columns in between the destination cells on the destination workbook, intended for comments about the said pasted data. I will also need to copy, paste and transpose said comments.

The s/s headers will look like this:

Data Comment Data Comment Data Comment

And so on and so forth.

I have tried numerous codes but always seem to get errors, the most recent being `Selection.Offset(, 2).Select, and End(xlUp).Offset(1, (x - 2) * 2)`.

Current code below which works perfectly, just unable to skip columns.

```
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Set wsDest = Workbooks("TL CSA Master v0.2.xlsx").Worksheets("Master")

Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Set wsSrc = Workbooks("CSA V0.4.xltm").Worksheets("CSA - TL")

Dim NextFreeRow As Long
NextFreeRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find next free row in Column A

wsSrc.Range("B2:B5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wsDest.Cells(NextFreeRow, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

wsSrc.Range("G9:G28").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wsDest.Cells(NextFreeRow, "E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Thanks in advance, I know this will seem so simple to most of you! I'm just trying to get to grips with it all!

Comment: I'm not seeing in your code where/how you want to skip columns. The first copy/paste shows copying four (visible) cells from a single column (B) to the destination range. The next copy takes 20 (visible) cells from a single column (G) to the destination.

Comment: Hi, sorry Peter, I haven't included the skip column code as I am unsure whereabouts I add this, and what the code should be. Thanks

Comment: I think Peter's point is that what you're doing isn't clear. You appear to be copying two unrelated ranges. What's the pattern?

Comment: Pattern? Apologies, I'm very new to coding and unsure on terminology. Let me attempt to explain this more clearly... So the code above copies data from one spreadsheet to another, and transposes it. The range of G9:G28 is now required to skip a column after every entry of data, (to allow for a comment in the neighbour column) but still be transposed. I am not sure where to insert the code which skips a column whilst transposing. I really hope I am making sense here, sincere apologies if not. I'm trying my best!